# How to retrieve Aggregate Roots that don't have repositories?

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, aggregateroot

Eric Evan's DDD book, pg. 152:

> Provide Repositories only for AGGREGATE roots that actually need
>   direct access.

1.
Should Aggregate Roots that don't need direct access be retrieved and saved via repositories of those Aggregate Roots that do need direct access?

For example, if we have `Customer` and `Order` Aggregate roots and if for whatever reason we don't need direct access to `Order` AR, then I assume only way *orders* can be obtained is by traversing `Customer.Orders` property?

2.
When should `ICustomerRepository` retrieve *orders*? When `Customer` AR is retrieved ( via `ICustomerRepository.GetCustomer` ) or when we traverse `Customer.GetOrders` property?

3.
Should `ICustomerRepository` itself retrieve *orders* or should it delegate this responsibility to a `IOrderRepository`? If the latter, then one option would be to inject `IOrderRepository` into `ICustomerRepository`. But since outside code shouldn't know that `IOrderRepository` even exists ( if outside code was aware of its existence, then it may also use `IOrderRepository` directly ), how then should `ICustomerRepository` get a reference to `IOrderREpository`?

**UPDATE:**

1

> With regards to implementation, if done with an ORM like NHibernate,
>   there is no need for an IOrderRepository.

a) Are you saying that when using ORM, we usually don't need to implement repositories, since ORMs implicitly provide them?

b) I do plan on learning one of ORM technologies ( probably EF ), but from little I did read on ORMs, it seems that if you want to completely decouple Domain or Application layers from Persistence layer, then these two layers shouldn't use ORM expressions, which also implies that ORM expressions and POCOs should exist only within Repository implementations?

c) If there is a scenario where for some reason AR root doesn't have a direct access ( and project doesn't use ORM ), what would your answer to 3. be?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm hard-pressed to think of an example where an aggregate does not require direct access. However, I think at the time of writing (circa 2003), the emphasis on limiting or eliminating traversable object references between aggregates wasn't as prevalent as it is today. Therefore, it could have been the case that a `Customer` aggregate would reference a collection of `Order` aggregates. In this scenario, there may be no need to reference an `Order` directly because traversal from `Customer` is acceptable.

With regards to implementation, if done with an ORM like NHibernate, there is no need for an `IOrderRepository`. The `Order` aggregate would simply have a mapping. Additionally, the mapping for `Customer` would specify that changes should cascade down to corresponding `Order` aggregates.

> When should ICustomerRepository retrieve orders?

This is the question which raises concern over traversable object references between aggregates. A solution provided by ORM is lazy loading, but [lazy loading can be problematic](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/06/16/orm-lazy-loading-pitfalls/). Ideally, a customer's orders would only be retrieved when needed and this depends on context. My suggestion, therefore, is to avoid traversable references between aggregates and use a repository search instead.

**UPDATE**

a) You would still need something that implements ICustomerRepository, but the implementation would be largely trivial if the mappings are configured - you'd delegate to the ORM's API to implement each repository method. No need for a IOrderRepository however.

b) For full encapsulation, the repository interface would not contain anything ORM-specific. The repository implementation would adapt the repository contract to ORM specifics.

c) Hard to make a judgement on a scenario I can't picture, but it would seem there is no need for Order repository interface, you can still have an Order Repository to better separate responsibilities. No need for injection either, just have the Customer repo implementation create an instance of Order repo.

Comment: I take it you usually don't completely decouple App/domain layer from persistence layer, simply because using ORM expressions in App/Domain layers offers so many benefits?

Comment: It depends on the project. Sometimes it isn't very valuable to abstract repository implementation. Other times it makes sense for encapsulation purposes. They key is not to over-engineer the abstraction.

Comment: I think that the most important is actually to understand that an Aggregate Repository is not a 1 <-> 1 relationship between your entity and a repository implementation, the Repository itself should represent how is designed your aggregate, and therefore your domain, in your case, you could gather both query to get Customer and Orders by Customer in your Repository without the need to do Object Traversal (let's say your Customers' Orders may get bigger and bigger), but as always, it depends™